# Developed R code for Fatal police shooting to deploy in shiny app ,But getting error in deployment

Tags: r

--This is the code I developed but when I try to deploy in shinyApps its not deploying. Not sure where I made a mistake, been stuck with this problem for a while...

Code starts from here:

```
    library(shiny)
    library(DT)
    library(leaflet)
    library(highcharter)
    library(ggplot2)
    
    
    ui <- fluidPage(
      
      
      titlePanel("Police Shootings in the U.S."),sidebarLayout(sidebarPanel(sliderInput("year","Select Year:",
                      min = 2015,max = 2020,value = 2020),
                      submitButton("Filter Data")),mainPanel(
```

#Tabset Panel

```
tabsetPanel(type = "tabs", tabPanel("View All Cases", dataTableOutput("view")),
                  tabPanel("Map of Cases", leafletOutput("map")),
                  tabPanel("Distribution of Race", plotOutput("race")),
                  tabPanel("Distribution of Gender", plotOutput("gender")),
                  tabPanel("Distribution of Threat Level", plotOutput("threat.level")),
                  tabPanel("Distribution of Flee", plotOutput("flee")),
                  tabPanel("Distribution of Age", plotOutput("age")),
                  tabPanel("Distribution of Armed", plotOutput("armed")),
                  tabPanel("Top 10 Cities with Most Victims", plotOutput("city"))))))


server <- function(input, output){
  filtered <- reactive({
    data <- read.csv("fatal-police-shootings-data.csv")
    data[data$year == input$year,]})
  output$view <- renderDataTable({
    datatable(filtered(),options = list(pageLength = 25))
  })
  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet(data = filtered()) %>%
      
      
      addTiles() %>%
      
      
      addCircleMarkers(~long, ~lat, popup = ~ paste(name, "<br>", age, "<br>", gender, "<br>", race, "<br>", "City:", city, "<br>", "State:",
                                                    state))
    
    
  })
```

#Plot the distribution of the variable "race" using a bar graph.

```
   output$race <- renderPlot({
    
    
    ggplot(filtered(), aes(x = race)) +
      
      
      geom_bar(fill = "blue") +
      
      
      theme_bw() +
      
      
      ggtitle("Distribution of Race") +
      
      
      xlab("Race")
    
    
  })
```

#Plot the distribution of the variable "gender".

```
  output$gender <- renderPlot({
    
    
    ggplot(filtered(), aes(x = gender)) +
      
      
      geom_bar(fill = "pink") +
      
      
      theme_bw() +
      
      
      ggtitle("Distribution of Gender") +
      
      
      xlab("Gender")
    
    
  })
```

#Plot the distribution of the variable "threat_level".

```
  output$threat.level <- renderPlot({
    
    
    ggplot(filtered(), aes(x = threat_level)) +
      
      
      geom_bar(fill = "darkgreen") +
      
      
      theme_bw() +
      
      
      ggtitle("Distribution of Threat Level") +
      
      
      xlab("Threat Level")
    
    
  })
```

#Plot the distribution of the variable "flee".

```
  output$flee <- renderPlot({
    
    
    ggplot(filtered(), aes(x = flee)) +
      
      
      geom_bar(fill = "brown") +
      
      
      theme_bw() +
      
      
      ggtitle("Distribution of Flee") +
      
      
      xlab("Flee")
    
    
  })
```

#Plot the distribution of the variable "age" (with geom_histogram() or geom_density() in ggplot2).

```
  output$age <- renderPlot({
    
    
    ggplot(filtered(), aes(x = age)) +
      
      
      geom_density(color = "red", fill = "green") +
      
      
      theme_bw() +
      
      
      ggtitle("Distribution of Age") +
      
      
      xlab("Age")
    
    
  })
```

#Plot the distribution of the variable "armed".

```
  output$armed <- renderPlot({
    
    
    ggplot(filtered(), aes(x = armed)) +
      
      
      geom_bar(fill = "yellow") +
      
      
      theme_bw() +
      
      
      ggtitle("Distribution of Armed") +
      
      
      xlab("Armed")
    
    
  })
```

#Plot the top 10 cities that have most victims.

```
  output$city <- renderPlot({
    
    
    ggplot(head(filtered(), 10), aes(x = reorder(city, desc(n)))) +
      
      
      geom_bar(fill = "grey") +
      
      
      theme_bw() +\
    
    
    ggtitle("Top 10 Cities with Most Victims") +
      
      
      xlab("City")
    
    
  })
  
  
}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  More useful would be knowing what the error you see on deploying actually is.  Have you looked at your deployment logs?  What do they tell you?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).